# JavaScript check if string contains @ symbol with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a quick test on a string to see if it contains the @ symbol.

The issue is that I don't know the syntax when using this symbol in regex.

Any help how to go from this:

```
if ( /test/.test(string) ) {
     return true;
}
```

To:

```
if ( /@/.test(string) ) {
     return true;
}
```

As the above returns a parse error.

Comment: A parse error? Are you sure that's the exact code you tried?

Comment: `@` has no special meaning in a regex and `/@/` is a perfectly fine regex.

Comment: Isn't a regex overkill for this? `if(value.indexOf('@') > -1)` is much more efficient and readable (ok, commonly understood / used).

Comment: @Rhumborl "Readable" is rather debatable there IMO. :)

Comment: You should use indexOf. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.includes()`

```
"a@b".includes("@")
 => true
```

> The `includes()` method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.
>
> Syntax
>       `str.includes(searchString[, position])`
>
> Parameters
>
> `searchString`
>       A string to be searched for within this string.
>
> `position` Optional
>       The position within the string at which to begin searching for searchString. (defaults to 0).
>
> Return value
>
> `true` if the search string is found anywhere within the given string; otherwise, `false` if not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes